# Go работа с Tarantool

Tags: база-данных, golang, tarantool

Все привет, в Tarantool создал простейшую схему с одной хранимой процедурой для получения данных:

```
local city_space = box.schema.space.create("city", {
    if_not_exists = true,
    format = {
        { "name", "string" }
    }
})
```

После чего из Go стараюсь получить данные:

```
type City struct {
    Name string
}

func GetAllCities() []entities.City {
    dbConnection := sources.GetDatabaseConnection()
    resp, err := dbConnection.Call("city.get_all", []interface{}{})
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(resp.Data) // выводит: [[Moscow] [Murmansk]] 
        // не понимаю, как распарсить resp.Data
        return []entities.City{}
    } else {
        fmt.Println("[city.get_all]: ", err)
        return []entities.City{}
    }
}
```

fmt.Println(resp.Data) выводит все верно - [[Moscow] [Murmansk]], но я не понимаю, как распарсить []interface{}, который возвращает Tarantool... Использую библиотеку: https://www.tarantool.io/ru/doc/latest/getting_started/getting_started_go/

Comment: Создать пустой (или сразу же с установленным размером исходя из `resp.Data`) срез типа `[]entities.City{}`. Пройтись циклом по `resp.Data` и собрать из него данные в целевой срез.

Comment: @7-zete-7 можете подсказать как именно это будет выглядеть и работать? приму ответ тогда

Answer (score 3):

Используйте функцию `CallTyped`. Эта функция принимает третьим аргументом пустой типизированный срез, в который должен быть записан результат.

Пример описанной реализации:

```go
func GetAllCities() []entities.City {
    dbConnection := sources.GetDatabaseConnection()
    var res []Tuple
    err := dbConnection.CallTyped("city.get_all", []interface{}{}, &res)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(resp.Data) // выводит: [{Moscow} {Murmansk}] 
        cities := make([]entities.City, len(resp.Data))
        for idx, item := range resp.Data {
            cities[idx] = entities.City{item[0]}
        }
        return res
    } else {
        fmt.Println("[city.get_all]: ", err)
        return []entities.City{}
    }
}
```

В коде используется функция `CallTyped` (вместо `Call`). Функция `CallTyped`, после получения результата, заполняет его в указанный типизированный срез.

Результатом этой функции, с помощью вызова `fmt.Println`, должно получиться (не особо многословное):

```
[{Moscow} {Murmansk}]
```

Comment: Код выдает ошибку компиляции: invalid operation: item[0] (type interface {} does not support indexing), я попробовал изменить на: cities[idx] = entities.City{Name: item.([]string)[0]} , но тогда падает в рантайме:  interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not []string

Comment: @QuickDzen, сложно оперировать с кодом не зная что прячется под interface{}. В исходниках библиотеки нашёл функцию `CallTyped`, которая была создана как раз для этой проблемы. Внёс правки в ответ.